# String comparison in PHP with general start and general end

Tags: php

I there a way to compare some string in php with this kind of syntax

```
STRINGS == %STRING%
```

I only want to know if someone know a way to do it like this

Comment: There's a bunch of string functions that accomplish that but no, their syntax is not like that.

Comment: `strpos()` is the PHP way or a `preg_match()`. Unfortunately, there's no `=~` operator like Perl & Ruby have to simplify the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take a leap and assume you mean SQL syntax for 'LIKE'.

For that, you use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Yes I mean a like sql syntax but with php. I'm gonna check what you tell me and brb

Answer (score 1):

You mean, you want to match part of a string? You can use [preg_match](http://ar.php.net/preg_match) and regular expressions for that.

```
if(preg_match("/string/", $myString)) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if a string is a substring of another string you could use the strpos function in PHP: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

For more generally uses, regular expressions is the way to go:
http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and
http://www.regularexpressions.info