# Using PHP to stop direct traffic to confirmation page

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to apply php to stop direct access to our sites confirmation page (Thank You page). We are under the impression that our affiliates may be triggering the conversion pixel to fire by visiting our confirmation page using its URL. This is making it appear that they have gotten us more payments than they actually did. We only want people to visit the page if they have completed a purchase. 
What I am currently attempting is to make it so they can only access the page if redirected from the URL that our form is hosted from. The problem I am running into is the link is always unique to each customer that makes a purchase.
However they all begin the same. I am unaware how to make it so it looks if the redirect url starts with a particular thing and basically ignores the following characters as they are always unique. I am inexperienced with php and the code I was able to find only looks for an exact match.

```
<?php
// This is to check if the request is coming from a specific URL
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if($ref !== 'http://example.com/page.html') {
  die("Hotlinking not permitted");
}

echo "Executing code here";
?>
```

Hopefully I am on the right track. 
Thank You in advance for any help on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for the command [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php).

But I recommend a diffrent solution because a lot of people use browser plugins that disable the referer in the Header and they would get a weird message.

Maybe take a look at [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) if its on the same server.

On diffrent servers you might have a shared medium like a MySql database where you can validate the user. You can also use a script and send a unique id between the servers to confirm the payment.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the URL using PHP's (you guessed it) `parse_url` function. It's explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Basically:

```
<?php
// This is to check if the request is coming from a specific URL
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$urlArray = parse_url($ref);

if($urlArray['host'] != 'example.com' && $urlArray['path'] != 'page.html') {
  die("Hotlinking not permitted");
}

echo "Executing code here";
?>
```

I have not tested this so you might want to see if `$urlArray['path']` and `$urlArray['host']` really returns what I think it does. You can check that with:

```
var_dump($urlArray['path']);
```

And adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is called [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). You can [match part of a string this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994580/string-comparison-in-php-with-general-start-and-general-end/9994635#9994635).

But be careful! The cheater will be able to set $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (for example: opening your page, adding a link to the `Thank You page` and clicking it.)

To solve it you should use sessions to check if the user really made a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the full issue with this.
You have customers on `payment_page.php` and they get forwarded to `thank_you.php`.
But if I go directly to `thank_you.php` you want to forward them to `index.php`. or something.

I would set a session variable on `payment_page.php` that it's a true customer.
Then at `thank_you.php` if the session variable is not there you redirect them to `index.php`

**Payment page**

```
Session_start();
$_SESSION["customer"] = true;
```

**Thank you.php**

```
Session_start();
If($_SESSION["customer"]){
    Echo "thank you";
}Else{
    //Redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well probably parse_url() php function can help you out:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$url1 = parse_url($ref);
$url2 = parse_url("http://example.com/page.html");

if ($url1['host'] != $url2['host']){
   //do this
   die("Hotlinking not permitted");
}

echo "Executing code here";
```